# Are values where $\sin x=0$ restrictions on $1/\cot x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to understand how to state restrictions on the following trig identity:

$\frac{1}{\cot x} = \sin x\sec x$

I understand why values of $x$ where $\cos x = 0$ are restrictions in this context (90° and 270°).

What I am having trouble understanding is why values of $x$ where $\sin x = 0$ qualify as restrictions (at least according to the solutions for my textbook). I am aware that $\cot x$ is undefined when $\sin x = 0$, but $\frac{1}{\cot x} = \tan x$... so why are 0°, 180°, and 360° also restrictions here? Moreover, when I use a graphing calculator to graph $\frac{1}{\cot x}$, this function is defined at 0°, 180°, and 360°.

Hoping someone can fill in my knowledge gap. Thanks.

Comment: Think of the function 1/(1/x). If you graph it, you'll see y=x, but with a discontinuity at x=0 since 1/x is not defined at that x-value. This implies 1(1/x) is "mostly" equal to x. The same applies here; 1/cotx = 1/(cosx/sinx) is "mostly" equal to tanx, but that sinx in the denominator means it is undefined at all x = 180n.

Comment: @shrey1 thanks a lot. I looked at the graph of $\frac{1}{cotx}$ again and realize that there are indeed discontinuities at those values of $x$... I didn't realize that I needed to hover over the graph for them to show up. cheers